# How to get image pop ups in QGIS 2.18?

Tags: popup, html, qgis-2.18, photos

I used to get image pop ups in QGIS using the HTML code:

**< img src="[% image %]" width=300 height=300 >**

But somehow, I do not manage to use it anymore on QGIS 2.18.

Does anybody have a clue?